# Where is 'clientapp/dist/vendor.js' referenced in Angular2Spa template?

Tags: angular, webpack

in the latest template version for [Angular2Spa](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/blob/dev/templates/Angular2Spa/webpack.config.vendor.js) , when you run `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js`, it generates 2 vendor.js files in 2 locations.

- wwwroot/dist/vendor.js  (generated by clientBundleConfig)
- clientapp/dist/vendor.js (generated by serverBundleConfig)

I know that `wwwroot/dist/vendor.js` is referenced in `index.html`.  But I don't understand why do we need to generate another file `clientapp/dist/vendor.js`

I couldn't find anywhere that file is referenced.  If anyone knows, could you please explain?